# How to read multiple data types from memoryview in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, floating-point, unsigned-integer

I am reading sensor data, which has 6 columns, first four are 32 bit floats, and the last two are unsigned integers. Here is how it is converted into a numpy array:

```
data = np.frombuffer(sensor_data.raw_data, dtype=np.dtype('float32')).reshape([-1, 6])
data = data[:, :5]

int_data = np.frombuffer(sensor_data.raw_data, dtype=np.dtype('uint')).reshape([-1, 6])
int_data = int_data[:, 4:6]
```

This doesn't seem like the most efficient way of doing this. Is there a way to either read multiple datatypes or covert the last two columns from `float32` back into bytes and then to `uint`?

Comment: It would be easier to create a correct solution if you explicitly state how many bytes each unsigned integer uses in the file.  `np.dtype('uint')` might be 4 bytes on some platforms and 8 bytes on others.

Answer (score 0):

If your 2 loads work, the unsigned ints must be 32 bit.

We can construct an equivalent structured array with a compound dtype:

```
In [58]: dt = np.dtype([('f0','f4',4),('f1','uint32',2)])                       
In [59]: arr = np.zeros(5, dt)                                                  
In [60]: arr['f0'] = np.random.rand(5,4)                                        
In [61]: arr['f1'] = np.random.randint(0,100,(5,2))                             
In [62]: arr                                                                    
Out[62]: 
array([([0.38565257, 0.36662674, 0.5530039 , 0.17866635], [39,  3]),
       ([0.12109676, 0.60092086, 0.6555444 , 0.06968965], [18, 96]),
       ([0.7082187 , 0.48962796, 0.4019332 , 0.19190358], [26, 81]),
       ([0.34053752, 0.35870123, 0.22802468, 0.33509415], [48, 52]),
       ([0.45730132, 0.38697603, 0.18952931, 0.90458447], [ 3, 40])],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4', (4,)), ('f1', '<u4', (2,))])
```

and create a data buffer:

```
In [63]: astr = arr.tobytes()
```

Your loads work with that buffer:

```
In [64]: data = np.frombuffer(astr, 'float32').reshape(-1,6)                    
In [65]: data[:,:4]                                                             
Out[65]: 
array([[0.38565257, 0.36662674, 0.5530039 , 0.17866635],
       [0.12109676, 0.60092086, 0.6555444 , 0.06968965],
       [0.7082187 , 0.48962796, 0.4019332 , 0.19190358],
       [0.34053752, 0.35870123, 0.22802468, 0.33509415],
       [0.45730132, 0.38697603, 0.18952931, 0.90458447]], dtype=float32)
In [66]: data = np.frombuffer(astr, 'uint32').reshape(-1,6)                     
In [67]: data[:,4:]                                                             
Out[67]: 
array([[39,  3],
       [18, 96],
       [26, 81],
       [48, 52],
       [ 3, 40]], dtype=uint32)
```

But we can also use the compound dtype to load it:

```
In [68]: data = np.frombuffer(astr, dt)                                         
In [69]: data['f0']                                                             
Out[69]: 
array([[0.38565257, 0.36662674, 0.5530039 , 0.17866635],
       [0.12109676, 0.60092086, 0.6555444 , 0.06968965],
       [0.7082187 , 0.48962796, 0.4019332 , 0.19190358],
       [0.34053752, 0.35870123, 0.22802468, 0.33509415],
       [0.45730132, 0.38697603, 0.18952931, 0.90458447]], dtype=float32)
In [70]: data['f1']                                                             
Out[70]: 
array([[39,  3],
       [18, 96],
       [26, 81],
       [48, 52],
       [ 3, 40]], dtype=uint32)
```

That compound dtype would also work with 'uint64'.

We could also get the `uint32` from the `float32` load by using `view`

```
In [84]: data = np.frombuffer(astr, 'float32').reshape(-1,6)                    
In [86]: data[:,4:].view('uint32')                                              
Out[86]: 
array([[39,  3],
       [18, 96],
       [26, 81],
       [48, 52],
       [ 3, 40]], dtype=uint32)
```

(or the float from the uint with a view)